# Getting and Passing variables inside React Native from Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

i'm using [react-native-webview][1] in my project React Native. My webview has a javascript array, i need get this Array and show the values inside one menu, like this Slide Menu:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/master/android.demo.gif

Code:

```
function WebViewPage(){
    const html = `
           <html>
           <body>
            <div id="reportContainer">here apear the content..</div>
            <script>
                  var reportContainer = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
                   var pages = [];
              reportContainer.getPages().then(function (reportPages) {
              //HERE RETURN A LIST FROM PAGES FROM MY REPORT..
              pages = reportPages;
              });
          </script>
          </body> 
           </html>
    `
   return(
    <Page>
     <WebView source={{html:html}} />
   </Page>
  );
}

export default WebViewPage;
```

Basically i need get the pages array and put on Menu at my Header. I was thinking work with hooks, but i don't know how to get this array, any ideas? Thank you.
[1]: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Why not just import your script ?

Comment: @BloodyMonkey At my webview show a Chart. This Chart has a many pages. I want to make a menu with a pages, when the user selected the Page on Menu, i have to send the page to webview again to open the specific chart at webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onMessage` callback function on `webview` component.

```
function WebViewPage(){
    const html = `
           <html>
           <body>
           <div id="reportContainer">here apear the content..</div>
           <script>
              var reportContainer = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
              var pages = [];
              reportContainer.getPages().then(function (reportPages) {
                 //HERE RETURN A LIST FROM PAGES FROM MY REPORT..
                 pages = reportPages;
                 window.postMessage(pages);
              });
           </script>
           </body> 
           </html>
    `
   const onMessage(data) { 
      console.log(data);
   }

   return(
    <Page>
     <WebView onMessage={onMessage} source={{html:html}} />
   </Page>
  );
}

export default WebViewPage;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you!!, i search this method onMessage and the correct is: `onMessage={(event) => onMessage(event.nativeEvent.data)}`. and to pass is: `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("parameter from webview");` Now i do to get :). How it works if i want pass something to webview now?

Comment: Here's a great example with an exaplanation. https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/12/27/injecting-custom-javascript-into-react-natives-webview/

Comment: And this also great tutorial for webview. https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-react-native-webview/

Comment: Thank you my Friend